# How to convert a string containing a list of dict into Python object?

Tags: python

```
ugly = "[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)},
         {'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]"
# The actual variable contains a lot more dictionnaries...`
```

I'd like to convert the ugly variable as a real Python object.
I tried `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval()` but it's for one dict only.

That's why, before that, I tried to split this string into several dictionnaries, but the `split()` method has only one delimiter, so it seems I could need a REGEX to do this.

What is the simplest way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: How did your list of dictionaries become a string in the first place?

Comment: Just to note, `ast.literal_eval` would work fine with a list of dicts; it doesn't like the `datetime` call.

Comment: @jDo Someone who prefers to store object as string rather than structured way in my company because we don't have time...

Comment: @DavidD. Yeah, okay. Makes sense - sort of

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well first you should be consistent in you calls to `datetime` method. In first dict, you use `datetime` and in second `datetime.datetime`.

Whatever way you try to have Python eval the string, you cannot have at the same time `datetime` be a function (first dict) and a module (second). Once you fix that, you will be forced to use the evil `eval` function, because neither `json.loads` not `ast.litteral_eval` will accept a function. They are normally used precisely to avoid the evaluation to call any function...

But if this is what you want to do (and you are sure that `ugly` contains no harmful code), this works:

```
>>> ugly = "[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)},{'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]"
>>> import datetime
>>> dlist = eval(ugly)
>>> dlist
[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)}, {'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]
```

Comment: Thanks! (and the other ones too for their answer)

Answer (score 6):

You can use eval

```
a = eval(ugly)
```

At this point a is a list of dictionaries and I am sure you got it from there.

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Please note that `eval` is dangerous. Use caution while you are using it. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @DavidD.you've got a `datetime` in one record and `datetime.datetime` in another. You need to make them consistent.

Comment: Bummer, looks like an issue with not having datetime.datetime on pickup-time... like Martin so quickly pointed out.

Comment: `eval(ugly.replace(' datetime(', ' datetime.datetime('))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to get the array of dictionaries (after fixing the `datetime` issue), and then use `setattr` to turn the dictionaries into real class objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

ugly = "[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)}, {'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]"
array = eval(ugly)

class Ride(object):
    pass

rides = []
for record in array:
    ride = Ride()
    for k, v in record.iteritems():
        setattr(ride, k, v)
    rides.append(ride)

for ride in rides:
    print "ride: {0}: pickup_time: {1}".format(ride.ride, ride.pickup_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to import `datetime`:

```
import datetime

ugly = "[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)},{'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]"
ugly = ugly.replace(" datetime(", " datetime.datetime(")
ugly = eval(ugly)
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime

ugly = "[{'ride': 1, 'pickup_time': datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202)},{'ride': 2, 'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202)}]"
ugly = ugly.replace("datetime.", "")
ugly = eval(ugly)
```

Both work without prior cleaning of `ugly`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a regex by extracting the `datetimes` and their keys only calling eval on those pairings:

```
from datetime import datetime
from ast import literal_eval
import re


def parse(ug):
    ug = ug.replace("datetime.", "")
    pairs = ("{{{}}}".format(p) for p in re.findall("('\w+':\s+datetime\(.*\))", ug))
    _parsed = literal_eval(re.sub("datetime\(.*\)","''", ug))
    for d in _parsed:
        d.update(eval(next(pairs)))
    return _parsed
```

The lists are going to be ordered so the correct pairing will be put back in the correct dicts:

```
In [4]: parse(ugly)
Out[4]: 
[{'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 36, 35, 976202),
  'ride': 1},
 {'pickup_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 15, 41, 35, 976202),
  'ride': 2}]
```