# Convert and slice Python string to list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, oop, apache-spark

I am given a raw string which is a path or "direction" to a string in JSON. 
I need the following string converted to a list containing dictionaries..

```
st = """data/policy/line[Type="BusinessOwners"]/risk/coverage[Type="FuelHeldForSale"]/id"""
```

The list should look like this

```
paths = ['data','policy','line',{'Type':'BusinessOwners'},'risk','coverage',{"Type":"FuelHeldForSale"},"id"]
```

I then iterate over this list to find the object in the JSON (which is in a Spark RDD)

I attempted `st.split(\)` which gave me

```
st.split('/')
Out[370]: 
['data',
 'policy',
 'line[Type="BusinessOwners"]',
 'risk',
 'coverage[Type="FuelHeldForSale"]',
 'CalculationDisplay']
```

But how do I convert and split items like `'line[Type="BusinessOwners"]'` to `'line',{'Type':'BusinessOwners'}`  ?

Comment: Hi. Did you try using eval()? Can you try this out:
st_new=eval(st)
Then print st_new. I hope this works.!

Comment: Hi! That did not work @ShrinivasDeshmukh data/policy/line[Type="BusinessOwners"]/risk/coverage[Type="FuelHeldForSale"]/id
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please refer to this link, a similar problem has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068779/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-a-list-of-dict-into-python-object

Comment: @mdeonte001 --- You should be a lot more specific as to what you want if you want people to use their time to solve your problem. If you want a dictionary in your list then state it instead of leaving others to read your mind!

Comment: @MichaelSwartz please see above, i state 'list containing dictionaries..' and in my example i show a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

first_list = st.replace('[', '/{"').replace(']', '}').replace('="', '": "').split('/')
[item if not "{" in item  else json.loads(item) for item in first_list]
```

or using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast

[item if not "{" in item  else ast.literal_eval(item) for item in first_list]


out:
['data',
 'policy',
 'line',
 {'Type': 'BusinessOwners'},
 'risk',
 'coverage',
 {'Type': 'FuelHeldForSale'},
 'id']
```

Comment: Hi, I ran this and I got the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'literal_eval' - what is ast.literal_eval(item) should that be st.literal?

Comment: sorry. you need to import ast first. please check again.

Comment: Not a huge fan of using literal_eval, but this is much better.

Comment: This works! Thank you. @MadPhysicist care share why you dislike literal_eval?

Comment: It certainly does work. I am wary of literal_eval because of things like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Aran-Fey/2667cef9420e930e57d80187a76e35e4). I am not 100% sure if it can be done exactly with literal_eval, but I would rather not take a chance.

Comment: Thank you  both - i really appreciate it. @MadPhysicist and Rahul I'm going to benchmark each of these in Spark and see what performs fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Would be more efficient if it wasn't a 1 liner, but I'll let you figure it out from here. Probably wanna come up with a more robust regex based parsing engine if your input varies more than your given schema. Or just use a standardized data model like JSON.

```
[word if '=' not in word else {word.split('=')[0]:word.split('=')[1]} for word in re.split('[/\[]', st.replace(']','').replace('"',''))]
```

> ['data', 'policy', 'line', {'Type': 'BusinessOwners'}, 'risk',
>   'coverage', {'Type': 'FuelHeldForSale'}, 'id']

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) may be a good tool here. It looks like you want to transform elements that look like `text1[text2="text3"]` with `text1, {text2: text3}. The regex would look something like this:

```
(\w+)\[(\w+)=\"(\w+)\"\]
```

You can modify this expression in any number of ways. For example, you could use something other than `\w+` for the names, and insert `\s*` to allow optional whitespace wherever you want.

The next thing to keep in mind is that when you do find a match, you need to expand your list. The easiest way to do that would be to just create a new list and [append/extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) it:

```
import re

paths = []
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\[(\w+)=\"(\w+)\"\]')
for item in st.split('/'):
    match = pattern.fullmatch(item)
    if match:
        paths.append(match.group(1))
        paths.append({match.group(2): match.group(3)})
    else:
        paths.append(item)
```

This makes a `paths` that is

```
['data', 'policy', 'line', {'Type': 'BusinessOwners'}, 'risk', 'coverage', {'Type': 'FuelHeldForSale'}, 'id']
```

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/CaIEkl)

I personally like to split the functionality of my code into pipelines of functions. In this case, I would have the main loop accumulate the `paths` list based on a function that returned replacements for the split elements:

```
def get_replacement(item):
    match = pattern.fullmatch(item)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), {match.group(2): match.group(3)}
    return item,

paths = []
for item in st.split('/'):
    paths.extend(get_replacement(item))
```

The comma in `return item,` is very important. It makes the return value into a tuple, so you can use `extend` on whatever the function returns.

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/cs7s9P)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in one line :

```
import re

pattern=r'(?<=Type=)\"(\w+)'
data="""data/policy/line[Type="BusinessOwners"]/risk/coverage[Type="FuelHeldForSale"]/id"""


print([{'Type':re.search(pattern,i).group().replace('"','')} if '=' in i else i for i in re.split('\/|\[',data)])
```

output:

```
['data', 'policy', 'line', {'Type': 'BusinessOwners'}, 'risk', 'coverage', {'Type': 'FuelHeldForSale'}, 'id']
```