# RegEx - Word after a certain match

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a RegEx question that I'm having a hard time finding a  solution. I want to process a list of strings of the type:

`genre = '[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]'`

These are the "genre" column of a movies dataframe I am working with.
I want to return a list of just the name of the genres. I've tried using re.match() and .search(). But I am too much of a RegEx beginner.

Could you help me with a solution for this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}` are key-value pairs, the entire expression is a list of dictionaries, see [Python list of dictionaries search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search), so Myke's answer is good, also see [How to convert a string containing a list of dict into Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068779/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-a-list-of-dict-into-python-object)

Comment: This is perfect and easy. Thank you and myke for your help. :D

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about regular expressions, but what about doing something like this?

```
list_ = eval('[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]')
[genre["name"] for genre in list_]
```

This is of course assuming that you only have the string. If you have the list itself, you don't need the workaround with `eval`. Also, watch out for security issues if your data is provided from an untrusted source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :D I was not familiar with this method. The thing is this string is repeated over a column of a dataframe. It's not just one, I want to receive the differente genres for a set of movies. Many, many thanks.

Comment: You should post the exact way your data is available to you.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I am newbie here.